# Variable value overwritten in getJSON function

Tags: javascript

I am working on a challenge in which I have to display Twitch channels that are offline and online. Here is the function that is having a bug:

```
function loadStreams(){
  for (var i = 0; i < channel_list.length; i++){
    offlineName = channel_list[i];
    console.log("offline name is: " + offlineName);
    URL = "https://wind-bow.hyperdev.space/twitch-api/streams/" + channel_list[i] + "?callback=?";
     $.getJSON(URL, function(data){
       console.log("Now offline name is: " + offlineName);
       console.log(data);
       if (data.stream !== null){
         currChannel = new Channel(data.stream.channel.display_name, data.stream.channel.status);
       }
       else {
         currChannel = new Channel(offlineName, "Offline");
       }       
       outArr.push(currChannel);
    });    
  }
  //showAll();
}
```

channe_list is an array of string preloaded with channel names. It is defined as follows:

```
var channel_list = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
```

My code is simply go through the channel_list, fetch the JSON data, and return the result and create a new instance of the Channel object, defined as:

```
var Channel = function(name, status){
  this.name = name;
  this.status = status;
}
```

For some reasons, in my else block, the variable "offlineName" is ALWAYS overwritten by the last value of the channel_list array, 'noobs2ninjas'. In other words, when I create an instance of the Channel class in the else block, "offlineName" is always "noobs2ninjas". Please let me know what i am doing wrong here. Here is my CodePen if you would like to take a look at the whole thing:

[https://codepen.io/tcao2/pen/XNbbbm?editors=1010](https://codepen.io/tcao2/pen/XNbbbm?editors=1010/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your issue

You might be aware of how fast a `for` loop runs (well it's very fast) but your network isn't fast at all when compared to and this is what causes you problem.Let me explain

You are using  $.getJSON with URL which has its value depend on `offlineName` but you are using `offlineName` in your success callback too.Now suppose for first req. `offlineName` is "ESL_SC2" now ajax request uses it in URL but as usual due to network latency the response doesn't arrive instantly meanwhile loop is now on second iteration .BUT wait `offlineName` IS "OgamingSC2" now!! and will be used so when your success callback of first request completes but wait there are even more entries so even "OgamingSC2" would get vanquished later on.Moreover the loop is so incredibly fast that by the time 1st or 2nd response comes in , your loop is already at its last iteration so only final `offlineName` value (noobs2ninjas) survives which is then used in success callback of all others.

**Solution:** The solution is to find some way by which each iteration would preserve its `offlineName` value and use the same in its corresponding success callback.The simplest way is to use `let` to declare `URL` and  `offlineName` which limits the scope per iteration it essence provide an effect similar to a closure

https://codepen.io/vsk/pen/LbNpBQ

Only problem with the above code is that `let` is a recent addition and older browsers don't support it well , so the other solution would be to actually implement a closure per request passing `URL` and `offlineName`

```
(function(url,name) {
   $.getJSON(url, function(data){
   if (data.stream !== null){
     currChannel = new Channel(data.stream.channel.display_name, data.stream.channel.status);
   }
   else {
     currChannel = new Channel(name, "Offline");
   }       
   outArr.push(currChannel);
  }); 
})(URL,offlineName);
```

https://codepen.io/vsk/pen/rWeOGL

**EDIT**: These are called *self-executing functions* and there is nothing special about them just a shorthand version of the code below

```
function hello(url,name){                //line #39
  //your code                           
}                                        //ln #53
hello(URL,offlineName);                  //ln #54
```

See [this](https://codepen.io/vsk/pen/dOMVKX) you'd find that it runs perfectly but the moment you comment out the function (line no. 39,53,54) it again reverts to the old bugged behavior.You might wonder how could a simple function change the behaviors so drastically.Here is how -  it's all based on *scope chains*

Just like Java the JS interpreter(referred as VM hereafter) reads your code line by line now when it reaches `hello`'s definition it just reads it (studies parameters,return and inside code) then moves on ; now it has reached the call  hello(URL,offlineName); it runs the code inside hello but then it realizes that `getJson` has a callback which can't be called at this moment so it records this in it's *"to be called later"* list along with the values of all variable used in that function **at that time** [1].So even if in later loop iterations `URL` and `offlineName` are reinitialized/assigned new values , they don't affect the values bound in [1] as they have no relation with them , they are totally different entities.This is because JS passes parameters by value(at least for primitive types)

But the most important thing about scope chains is that even after the loop gets over the values referenced in `getJson` callback are still there only thing is you can't access them directly but VM can .The reason is - the last function in the chain is a callback (recorded in list) and so to make any sense VM must let survive the values needed by it when it runs in the future , nerds call it a closure where inner function will always have access to things present in outer function even thought outer function call is over and control has returned somewhere else.Note that even in your earlier bugged code values were getting saved only problem was they were getting overwritten because for all of them had only one outer function ie `loadStreams` but when you create and call separate `hello`s each one creates a separate environment(something like a parallel universe).

In essence it creates scope chains so each iteration can have it's "Own space" where it's free from interference by others.

`for loop --> hello() --> getJson's inner function` (per iteration)

You might go well with `let` but first have a look at compatibility chart at http://caniuse.com/#feat=let

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply Novice! It's interesting to see that the problem is with the speed of the network and how fast the loop runs ( I am used to Java, just started learning js and web dev). The first solution makes sense to me (I will have to look into the 'let' keyword), but for the second solution, what does the closure do?

Comment: Thank you so much!!